# Error Using Nebula With Angular 17 Standalone components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, nebular

While trying to add Nebula to my angular 17 standalone project,
using this in my app config.ts

i get errors such as
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideToastr(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideToastr(),
     importProvidersFrom(NbThemeModule.forRoot({
      name: 'default',
    }))]
};
```

and this in my view

```
<nb-layout>
  <nb-layout-header fixed>Company Name</nb-layout-header>

  <nb-sidebar>Sidebar Content</nb-sidebar>
  
  <nb-layout-column>
    Page Content <button nbButton>Hello World</button>
  </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

Comment: can you share the code on stackblitz for example

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I noticed was that you are missing `importProvidersFrom(NbSidebarModule.forRoot())` in the `app.config.ts` other that that your code seems proper, also are you importing the `NbLayoutModule`, `NbSidebarModule` in the imports array of the component that is using them?

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ash5uj?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fangular.json,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.config.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.config.server.ts&title=node.new%20Starter) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`

---

You have a typo on the below line. Missing few closing brackets!

```
...
provideToastr(),
importProvidersFrom(NbThemeModule.forRoot({
  name: 'default',
})) // <- changed here!
]
...
```

Comment: yea thanks, i have corrected that, but i am still facing the issues i raised